# Implement Windows Phone 7 Pager (Tab switching, pivots, panorama etc) UI in Android App?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, user-interface, android-viewpager

Can someone help me figure out how to code in Windows Phone 7 like Pager UI into an Android app?
I am refering to the behavior of switching between several tabs(or pages if you will).
I know how to use View Pagers, but im unable to figure out the logic to do this.

For example the switching between artists, albums etc implemented in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.odesanmi.and.wpmusic

Or the settings implemented in Launcher 7
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.tikuwarez.launcher3&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiaW5mby50aWt1d2FyZXoubGF1bmNoZXIzIl0.

Very Specifically i would like to know to know how to switch those tab names along with the actual page. I was wondering if this might even be possible with two Viewpagers, but im not sure of how to synchronize them, if such a thing is even possible.